# Problems with copying data

Tags: excel, vba, copy, copy-paste, paste

I'm having a problem with a code to copy and paste based on column headings (code included at the bottom of this post).

The macro should search for a column heading and then copy the data under that heading and paste the data in a new location (under a different heading in a new workbook). The code works in most cases because I have used it to copy data from certain columns (e.g. A, B, C all in the same worksheet), and the code works fine. I think the paste destination is also fine because I can run the macro to copy data from these columns (e.g. A, B, C) and paste into my destination. However, for some reason when I try and copy data from column F, and paste in a new worksheet, nothing happens. I don't even get an error message. Because I can copy from other columns, and paste into the target column, my thoughts are that the error is with the copy part of the marco.

I've checked the obvious like does the column headings in my code match exactly with the column headings in the document, etc. Is there something wrong with my code, or is it possible there's something in the source worksheet that is preventing certain data from being copied?

```
Sub ProjectCopy()
Dim sourceWS As Worksheet, targetWS As Worksheet
Dim lastCol As Long, lastRow As Long, srcRow As Range
Dim found1 As Range, found2 As Range

Set sourceWS = Workbooks("Workbook1.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Needs to be open
Set targetWS = Workbooks("Workbook2.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Needs to be open

With sourceWS
    lastCol = .Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set srcRow = .Range("A1", .Cells(1, lastCol))
    Set found1 = srcRow.Find(What:="Project", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

    If Not found1 Is Nothing Then
        lastCol = targetWS.Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set srcRow = targetWS.Range("A1", targetWS.Cells(1, lastCol))
        Set found2 = srcRow.Find(What:="Activity", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

        If Not found2 Is Nothing Then
            lastRow = .Cells(Rows.count, found1.Column).End(xlUp).Row
            .Range(.Cells(3, found1.Column), .Cells(lastRow, found1.Column)).Copy
            found2.Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        End If
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hard to tell without your data. Have you debugged your code to see where it doesn't' behave as expected?

Comment: I'm getting an error in "Set sourceWS" and "Set targetWS" lines - not sure why since these lines work fine when I search for other column headings and the docs are open. Also getting an error in the "With sourceWS" section. Again with the exception of the heading name to search for, this exact code works fine with other heading names.

Comment: What is the actual error you are getting when setting sourceWS and targetWS? Also, try changing your copy statement to: **`.Range(.Cells(3, found1.Column), .Cells(lastRow, found1.Column)).Copy found2.Offset(1, 0)`** (all in the same line of code)

Comment: Hi @Zac I've tried making this change but still nothing happening. The error message is "identifier under cursor is not recognised"

Comment: Have you stepped through your code? If so then, does it even get to the copy statement considering that you are getting an error when attempting to set the source and target? I suspect that you have set **"On Error Resume Next`** somewhere and that's why it keeps going. At the start of your sub, reset that with: **"On Error Goto 0"**

Comment: @Zac I didn't have an error line in the original code but have added in the one you suggested. I can still step through the full code and the copy part highlights as an error but no message for this part

Comment: So even though you are getting an error when setting your worksheets, you are able to continue? Are workbook1 and workbook2 already open when you run the above code because you are not opening them?

Comment: Yeah, I don't really understand why! Both workbook 1 and 2 are open before the macro is run

Comment: Had a quick search and it seem that some people with same error resolved the issue by simply restarting there PC. Can you try that?